# Account is not allowed to suggest edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just noticed that I can't edit posts anymore? The edit button is disabled with the info-tip :

> account is not allowed to suggest edits

I Googled about this and apparently this is caused by having edits being rejected.   Maybe I did not pay attention but how we know that an edit we made was rejected?

How many rejected edits ban a user from suggesting edits and for how long? For my situation when can I be able to suggest edits again?

Comment: Looking at your recent edits, especially the rejected ones, it seems that you often fix only a few issues in a post, sometimes also sprinkle on some arbitrary bold/italic/code formatting (which is often unnecessary) or linebreaks, but fail to address the remaining issues like capitalisation, punctuation, etc. So my recommendation would be that if you're going to edit a post, take the time to do it properly and fix all problems with it, not just some. Also, make sure that any formatting you add is actually required and an improvement.

Comment: I'm not so perfect to claim that I can fix ``all`` the problems with a post, I try to do my best. For example in this ``Am curious`` even if it is __understandable__ and you may judge it fix-free, I tend to fix it to ``I am curious``. The arbitrary formatting like you said, is meant just to render the question more 'readable' by everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [view your suggested edits](https://superuser.com/users/166486/hicham-lemghari?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) on your user profile under activity.

An account is prohibited from making suggestions after a certain number of rejected edits. You will automatically regain the ability to suggest edits after 7 days. It is not possible for a moderator to reinstate edit privileges manually; you must wait until 7 days have passed.

Comment: I see, I still think it lacks a little of clarity, (like showing the status in front of each suggested edit : pending|Approved|Rejected). Thanks for your help

Comment: @HichamLEMGHARI Feel free to voice your opinion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor).

Comment: Yeah, Upvoted the suggestion :); I'm new to meta and to SE in general